# When YouTube api chart changed , mostPopular To bts , why it is not working

Tags: api, charts, keyword

useEffect(() => {
axios
.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=8&regionCode=KR&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_YOUTUBE_API_KEY}`)
.then(response => {
createVideoCards(response.data.items);
})

Answer (score 0):

You have to select charts in most popular video by 'videoCategoryId'.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22contentDetails%22%2C%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22chart%22%3A%22mostPopular%22%7D#chart

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32977941)